# Find probability using distribution function method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables with distribution $U(0,1)$. Let $Y=|X_1-X_2|$. Find the distribution function and density of $Y$.

Solution: 
f(x1)=1 whenever x1 between 0 and 1
         =0 Else where
f(x2)=1 whenever x2 between 0 and 1
         =0 Else where
f(x1,x2)=1 whenever x1,x2 between 0 and 1
          =0 Else where
G(y)= P[-y <= x1-x2 <= y]
      =\int_{-y}^y \int_{x1_y}^{y+x1} 1 dx2 dx1
      =\int_{-y}^y -2y dx1
      =4y^2 when y between 0 and 1
      =0 when y less than 0
      =1 when y greater than 1
Thus, g(y)= \diff G(y) =8y 
Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry iam bad with commands

Comment: You should use MathJax, state what the D.F. method is, and state what the question is.

Comment: I tried the commands on integral but didnt work

Comment: Sorry i forgot the question my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we plot the region
$$
\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2: |x-y|\leqslant t\}
$$
for $t\in(0,1)$, we see that it consists of all of $[0,1]^2$ except for the triangles with vertices $(t,0),(1,0),(1,1-t)$ and $(0,t), (0,1)$ and $(1-t,1)$. These are right triangles each with area $\frac12(1-t)^2$, and so the distribution function of $Y$ is
$$
G(t) = 1 - (1-t)^2.
$$
Differentiating yields the density
$$
g(t) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt} G(t) = 2(1-t).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :D